# Load an image in WordPress with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, path

I'm developing a template page for WordPress, I need to load an image when I click a button the path is `namesite.com/wordpress/test` and I need to load an image

```
$("<img src='wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/loader.gif' class='loader' />").appendTo("#contact");
```

The problem is that the image isn't searched in `wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/loader.gif` but in `wordpress/test/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/loader.gif` so I have error. How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepend the img src with '/' to start at the root. Ex:

```
$("<img src='/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/loader.gif' class='loader' />").appendTo("#contact");
```